# Duplicate an AR record & re-insert this into the database

Tags: php, database, activerecord, yii

I have a AR model that I am trying to duplicated but just need to manually change the foreign key.

```
$_POST['competition_id'] = 99;
$prizes = CompetitionPrizes::model()->findAll('competition_id =:competition_id',array(':competition_id'=> $_POST['competition_id']));
```

This query basically queries the prizes table and gets all the rows for a particular competition. With the prizes object I would like to basically re-insert/duplicate the same information except the competition id which I want to manually set.

I did something similar for an AR object that basically only has one row and that worked well, however in this instance as a competition can have more than one prize this same code won't.

```
// My existing code for duplication process
$obj = Competitions::model()->find('competition_id=:competition_id', array(':competition_id' => $post['competition_id']));
$clone = clone $obj;
$clone->isNewRecord = true;
unset($clone->competition_id); // i want to remove this so it is auto inserted instead via the db
$clone->save();
```

This works great - how would I modify this on a 'collection' of prizes and have this duplicated into the database while setting my own 'competition_id' value.

Note - i'm to new to Yii, so please let me know if I have made any obvious errors/bad practice

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Cloning won't work. You need to assign the attributes to a new object:

```
$obj = Competitions::model()->find('competition_id=:competition_id', array(':competition_id' => $post['competition_id']));
$clone = new Competitions;
$clone->attributes = $obj->attributes;
$clone->save();
```

Comment: How would I do this same process on the $prizes which will return an array of more than one item?

Comment: Something like this:
`foreach($models as $model) {
  $clone = new Competitions;
  $clone->attributes = $model->attributes;
  $clone->save();
}`

Comment: Brill! I'll give that a shot mate!

Comment: But be careful: in this row `$clone->attributes = $obj->attributes;` you assign values only to the safe attributes ([http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#setAttributes-detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#setAttributes-detail))

Comment: How can we clone all attributes that have values, regardless of validation rules?

Answer (score 5):

If a more generic way of duplicating a Model / ActiveRecord in Yii2 Framework is required, you might use this solution:

```
$copy = clone $model;
$copy->isNewRecord = true;
foreach ($model->getPrimaryKey(true) as $field => $value) {
    unset($copy->{$field});
}
$copy->save();
```

GitHub issue discussion about duplicate models: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7544#issuecomment-77158479

Answer (score 4):

The answer for my problem although Michiel above helped me out - alternatively if you wouldn't mind adding another answer i'll give you the accepted answer.

```
foreach($models as $model) 
{ 
   $clone = new Competitions;
   $clone->attributes = $model->attributes;
   $clone->competition_id = '123' // custom var i am setting manually.
   $clone->save(); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about (yii2 syntax):

```
$model=Competitions::findOne([':competition_id' => $post['competition_id']]);
$model->id = null;
$model->isNewRecord = true;
$model->save();
```

Comment: On postgresql this is good only if table is without primary key, if you are forcing NULL to this column you will get an error , so if 'id' is primary key then workaround is to replace: $model->id = null; with unset($model->id); Also you must take care of unique fields!

Comment: R U shure about this?
I mean I am not using postgree, but is'n there auto increment function?

Comment: Yes I tried it, and column 'id'  is a 'serial' (equivalent to 'AI' column), but PDO report an error with failed PK constraint. Unset solved the problem. I have not test it on any other RDBM. Anyway your solution for duplication is good.

Comment: This did not work for me when using MS SQL.  I was able to "clone" the record by following @Michiel 's answer.

Comment: This is the simplest solution. Thanks!