# yii2 create row copy in db (insert copied object with the same attributes)

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have to check in my db if the row with the same id exists. And if it does, I should do a new insert in my db, but with the same attributes.

How can I create a new model object with the same attributes ? Cloning doesn't work, because Yii2 just update the old model instead of create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two new models  and populate both  eg: in  actionTwoInsert

```
public function actionTwoInsert()
  {
      $model1 = new MyModel();
      $model2 = new MyModel();
      $model1->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
      $model2->load(Yii::$app->request->post()); 
      model1->save();
      model2->save();    

  }
```

Comment: that is works http://stackoverflow.com/a/20995213/6651006